# Flip Fluids Not Updating Per Frame

Tags: fluid-simulation

Edit: Problem solved. Turns out it was a conflict with the Photographer addon. Disabling Photographer lets the Fluids update frame by frame in the render.

I've made a fluid sim using the latest version of the Flip Fluids addon.

Problem is, for each frame I need to manually click "Reload Frame" to get the fluid to update. When I render the animation, everything animates fine, except the fluid which stays in the first frame of the sim.

When I very first open the file and play through it in the timline, it works fine. But the moment I click render animation, it locks the fluid to the first frame. Then I need to reload the file to get it to update per frame automatically again.

I've got persistent data turned off, I even tried manually keyframing the fluid to start at the correct frame and progress through but it won't automatically update.

Does anybody have any ideas? I'm pulling my hair out over here.

I'm using Blender 3.1 and Flip Fluids 1.4.0

Comment: Could you share your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: My blend file is almost 1gb but I can upload if needed.

At the moment I have this error log:
https://pastebin.com/AACsWuw6

Comment: This may be a cache problem. Try rebaking in another folder or try copy-pasting all the fluid objects into a new file, save your new file, and then bake.

Comment: Fixed: It turns out it was a conflict with the Photographer addon. As soon as I disable that, the Flip Fluids work perfectly.